# Find the integral: $\int x^{7/2} sec^2(2+x^{9/2}) \mathrm{d}x$

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

Find the integral: $\int  x^{7/2} sec^2(2+x^{9/2}) \mathrm{d}x$

Can I multiply and distribute the $ \ x^{7/2}\ $ and $ \ sec^2 \ $ together. 
What is the strategy to solve this problem.

Comment: Substitution of variables, let $y=x^{9/2}+2$.

Comment: Why did you write it backwards? Anyway, I should use " U" substitution?

Comment: Compare the monomial inside and the one outside and you see that the one outside is the interior derivative up to a multiplicative constant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may just perform the change of variable $u=2+x^{9/2}$, $du=\dfrac92x^{7/2}\:dx$, giving
$$
\int  x^{7/2} \sec^2(2+x^{9/2})\: \mathrm{d}x=\dfrac29\int \sec^2(u) \:\mathrm{d}u= \dfrac29\tan (u)+C.
$$
Can you take it from here?

Answer (score 3):

Substitute $u=$ the term inside the parentheses.

Comment: After I do that can I distribute.

Comment: @ Cetschwayo: you won't need to distribute. See the solution provided by @Olivier Oloa. Incidentally, regarding strategy, whenever a comstant multiple of the derivative of the "inside" function multiplies the "outside" function, use the sunstitution $u=$ the "inside" function.